# Is it possible to read how bluetooth notifications are currently configured in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, core-bluetooth

The documentation on [ANCS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html) is pretty clear that you can react to notifications when they are coming in, have come in, and when they are cleared from the Notification Center; however, what if I wanted to give a user the ability to configure my Bluetooth 4.0 accessory to only respond to notifications coming from a specified app?

The ideal UI for this would be a simple list of apps they either have installed or apps that have been granted access to the notification center with an on/off switch.

Thanks for editing! I wasn't sure if we were "allowed" to link to Apple documentation or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of the installed apps, *there is no dedicated API*. You can use the [URL scheme trick](http://maniacdev.com/2012/11/open-source-ios-library-for-detecting-apps-installed-on-a-users-device) to detect whether an app is present but its enabled state in the notification center is not detectable in any way. However, based on the URL scheme app list, you can configure your peripheral for a subset of the installed applications and you can provide additional options for the user for other apps. (Though, I think most apps that come into consideration for you should have URL schemes.)